Creating dummy variables for an R dataframe based on various groupings of months
Assume I have a dataframe with one column of class "Date" in R:
       Date      Sales      Type   
1 2012-03-22      22          A      
2 2012-03-22      18          B      
3 2012-04-11      20          C      
4 2013-05-03      26          A      
5 2013-05-03      15          C     
6 2015-06-12      29          A      
7 2015-07-15      22          B      

I want to create dummy variables for certain groupings of months in order to run various linear and glm models. For instance, if I form 3 groups consisting of months {3}, {5} and {6,7} respectively, I want 3 dummy variables, call them Dummy1, Dummy2 and Dummy3 respectively to get the following table:
       Date      Sales      Type   Dummy1  Dummy2  Dummy3
1 2012-03-22      22          A      1       0       0
2 2012-03-22      18          B      1       0       0
3 2012-04-11      20          C      0       0       0
4 2013-05-03      26          A      0       1       0
5 2013-05-03      15          C      0       1       0
6 2015-06-12      29          A      0       0       1
7 2015-07-15      22          B      0       0       1  

How can I achieve this?

I would first create a column with the value you want dummied, for your example using library(tidyverse) I would do your_data |> mutate(to_dummy = case_when(month(Date) == 3 ~ "m3", month(Date) == 5 ~ "m5", month(Date) %in% c(6, 7) ~ "m6.7", .default = NA)) and  then use any standard approach to turn it into dummy columns such as in these answers.

Compare the month m to each of the group levels as shown:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

m <- month(dat$Date)
dat |> mutate(Dummy1 = +(m == 3), Dummy2 = +(m == 5), Dummy3 = +(m %in% 6:7))

or without packages
m <- dat$Date |> as.Date() |> format("%m") |> as.numeric()
dat |> transform(Dummy1 = +(m == 3), Dummy2 = +(m == 5), Dummy3 = +(m %in% 6:7))


 


library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  mutate(across(Date, list(~ +(month(.) == 3), 
                           ~ +(month(.) == 5), 
                           ~ +(month(.) %in% 6:7)), .names = "Dummy{.fn}"))

Or
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(x = case_match(month(Date), 3 ~ 1, 5 ~ 2, 6:7 ~ 3, .default = NA)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = "Dummy", names_from = x, values_from = x, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0L) |>
  select(-any_of("DummyNA"))

